# http error 503 in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: http, iis-8

We have 4 web applications installed on IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012. 3 websites and 1 webService.  One website is functioning fine.  Hitting the urls for the other sites get "HTTP Error 503 Service  Unavailable". The HttpErr log has 
".http 1.1..Get websiteName 503 1 N//A websiteAppPoolName".

I cannot find any error messages in any of the Event Logs: Application, System or Security. I also cannot find anything related to 503 dash 1 in any Microsoft
 documentation.
The same versions of these apps run fine on Windows 2008 Server.

I have read many posts about 503, and the application pool identity for all sites is valid, and unlike the typical 503 error caused by an expired credential for the app pool, when the 503 is recorded, the app pool is still started.

Note that there is a mixture of 32-bit and 64-bit web apps. The functioning site is 64-bit. The other 3 were 32-bit. Their app pools are set to enable 32-bit. Thinking this might be a part of the problem, 
I converted the webservice to 64-bit, changing the app pool accordingly, no difference, still get 503.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in another Stack Overflow post about the 503 error, but I am not sure which one. However, David McClendon provided the answer.
Under /Advanced Settings for the website, under Enabled Protocols, there was this: http; https. The colon should be a COMMA. Once this was changed, sites were hunky dory. Very frustrating that IIS logs no information about the cause of the error.,